# Grouped options for html select and updating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an input and a drop down on a page for a city and country respectively on an edit page:

```
  = f.input :city
  = f.input :country, collection: country_list
```

And here how it is updated on the server:

```
  if @my_model.update_attributes(get_permitted_params) #...
```

I want to replace them with one drop down containing `grouped_options_for_select` to make it show cities and countries as the same time:

```
= f.select(:city, grouped_options_for_select(country_with_cities_list))
```

1. What do I have to use as the first argument in `f.select`? It's not only city and it's not only country. It's both.
2. Will I have to change anything in 
   `if @my_model.update_attributes(get_permited_params) #...` to remain it functioning as before?

Comment: For the first input, do you mean `= f.input :city`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still have to use `:city` as the first argument for that form field.

Using `grouped_options_for_select`, you **only** tend to group together set-of-cities under an `optgroup` label of a country. But, you will only end up selecting an `option` of a city. Example:

```
<optgroup label="England">
  <option value="Bedfordshire">Bedfordshire</option>
  <option value="Berkshire">Berkshire</option>
  <option value="Bristol">Bristol</option>
</optgroup>
```

If you have to set-up the `country` too, you will have to do that manually at controller side.
For `country_with_cities_list`, make sure that it corresponds to an array as `[["England", ["Bedfordshire", "Berkshire", "Bristol"]],...]` (or it's equivalent hash).

Something like below(untested) can help. It groups set of cities(and their corresponding ids) for a country:

```
@cities = City.all(include: country)
country_with_cities_list = @cities.inject({}) do |hash, city|
  (hash[city.country.name] || = []) << [city.name, city.id]
  hash
end
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know how to implement the same thing (create `optiongroup -> option` select)  but using `f.input :city, collection: my_collection`, meaning - via `f.input` and `collection`?

Comment: Do you mean by using `simple_form` or `formtastic`? `f.input` with `collection` is not a generic Rails' form builder API.

Comment: never mind, I figured that out. However, yes, I need **both** country and city at the server city. And I'd like **not** to look for a country by the city I received. I'd like to **receive** them via the POST params. Is it possible?